# Iterating over arrays simultaneously using jq

Tags: arrays, json, loops, jq

I'm describing the output I'd like to have using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Here my json file

```json
{
  "partitions": [
    {
      "replicas": [
        0,
        1,
        2
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "replicas": [
        2,
        0,
        1
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
[...]
```

I would like, for every object in partitions[] to replace the value of the i th string in log_dirs[] by its concatenation with the i th number in replicas[] in order to have something like this

```json
{
  "partitions": [
    {
      "replicas": [
        0,
        1,
        2
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any0",
        "any1",
        "any2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "replicas": [
        2,
        0,
        1
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any2",
        "any0",
        "any1"
      ]
    },
[...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `reduce` loop with a `range`

```
.partitions[] |= reduce range(0; ( .replicas | length ) ) as $r 
  ( . ; .log_dirs[$r] += ( .replicas[$r] | tostring ) )
```

The reduce expression works by iterating over the entire `log_dirs` array upto the length of `replicas` list and modifying each entry `.log_dirs[$r]` (here `r` runs from 0 - length of `replicas`) by appending the corresponding value at `replicas[$r]`. Since `replicas` contains numerics, it needs to be converted to string for the append operation.

[jqplay - demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jmoVwLwKKr)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation  

I'm going to play with a it a bit to master it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite happy with this, but it does work:

```
jq '.partitions[] |= . + (
  . as $p | {
    log_dirs: [
      range(.replicas | length) |
      "\($p.log_dirs[.])\($p.replicas[.])"
    ]
  }
)' in.json
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works as well but I can't upvote sorry 

EDIT: Now I can :)